# Question about AB - Global High Yield Portfolio AA GBP

Tags: mutual-funds

I have some GBP currency lying around that I don't know what to do with. And no I don't live in the United Kingdom. So I was looking to investing in something safe like this bond fund: https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/summary?s=LU1069345764:GBP

But curiously enough, this fund and the comparable Global High Yield Bond GBP Hedged have since inception in 2014 been on a straight trajectory downward in value. Now clearly it isn't anything wrong with this fund in particular, but something to do with GBP Hedged bonds. My question is now looks like a good time to buy since it's at its lowest price point ever. And the fixed bond income is nice. But can someone explain to me why this product since 2014 has been on a straight-downhill trajectory? Is there hope for its value to rise in the future? Thanks.

Comment: Advice on specific bonds or stocks is out of scope here. If you make this a general question about "should I be concerned if a bond with good returns has been declining in value for almost a decade?", and make this an example of the pattern, I think that's more innkeeping with our goals here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bond ETFs are not truly "fixed income" as you are not guaranteed a specific coupon or principal over time. They consist of hundreds or thousands of bonds that meet its investment criteria. Those bonds can change in value over time as interest rates change, and if bonds mature or are redeemed early and are replaced with new bonds, the average coupon yield that the fund receives internally can change, changing the
"interest" payment that the fund pays out.

A "Global High-Yield" fund will be exposed to interest rate changes all over the globe, both government "risk-free" rates and the higher yield that corporate bonds get as a result of additional risk of default. So there's not one thing that can explain the drop in value over time, but the largest factor is likely interest rates increasing since 2022 in the US and over a longer time in other countries.

> But can someone explain to me why this product since 2014 has been on a straight-downhill trajectory?

The *total return* (the price return of the fund plus the dividend) of both funds looks to be slightly increasing over the past 5 years, with explainable dips in 2020 (COVID) and 2022 as US (and other) interest rates rose.

> Is there hope for its value to rise in the future?

There is *hope*, yes - interest rates could start to go back down, which will increase the value of the fund (but might decrease the dividend over time) but nothing is certain.

If you just want to earn some risk-free interest on your GBP currency, I don't think this is the best way to do it. Investing in a bond fund is essentially a bet on interest rates in the future.